# Recovering a String SQL Sentence with variables to use it

Tags: c#, sql-server, variables

I have the following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE Type = 'Test type' 
AND Description = 'Number: " + row["Doc"].ToString() + "' 
AND State = 1
```

The `row["Doc"].ToString()` is coming from a foreach loop that iterates over a datatable reading the `Doc` field.

My deal is to store the full sentence in a SQL Server table like a String, then recover it. Here I have no problem but when I want to use the sencence, my code can not translate the real `row["Doc"].ToString()` data, it understands it like a real string and my SQL sentence, obviously, is not working.

To explain it better, I need to execute the sentence but it seems a full string, without variables. I don't know how to recover and replace the variables with their values.

Comment: Please add more code to understand the context.

Comment: Sorry,  I will try again. 

If I want to store the query: '"SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = " + variable1', where 'varable1' take its value from the context, I can save all the query in a nvarchar(MAX) field (for example) or divide the query in two fields, saving 'variable1' in a second nvarchar(30) field.
When I recover the query, the variable1 is recovered like a string and the code understands the string  '"SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.ID =  + variable1"'.  The fact is that I have no idea of how to make the word "variable1" to be understood like a variable, not like a string.

Answer (score 2):

Very unclear what you're asking, I'm trying to guess.

You have in your code something like this:

```
string theQuery = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Type = 'Test type' AND Description = 'Number: " 
    + row["Doc"].ToString() + "' AND State = 1";
```

Then you have somewhere else something like this:

```
string storeQuery = "INSERT INTO sometable(query) VALUES('" + theQuery + "')";
```

If that's correct then obviously the second query will never work as it already contains some chars which must be escaped in order to not to break the query.

To do that, use a query parameter which means creating a prepared statement that properly escapes all the parameters and also takes care of a part of SQL injection problem:

```
string storeQUery = "INSERT INTO sometable(query) VALUES(@param1)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storeQUery, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", theQuery);
```

**Also, for your knowledge, concatenating the SQL queries manually is one of the biggest security holes you can create, any malicious user can execute an SQL injection attack.**

Comment: `AddNamedParameterWithValue`? Is this a new method of the MySql connector? (By the way the question is tagged Sql Server)

Comment: @Steve ehm, no, its not new, its part  of the ado mysql command, and yes, it must be sql, let me change it (i read on the description "my SQL" and my head just joined tham :D)

Comment: Perhaps my Intellisense is broken but I can't find any method with that name on MySqlCommand class (version 6.3.6.0)

Comment: @Steve hell, that's what happens for writing code from memory, corrected, it's .Parameters.AddWithValue :P